# Use PIE to count the number of $6$-multisets of $[6]$ in which no digit occurs more than twice.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

This is one of a set of several problems in my book I am having difficulty not just solving, but also understanding the provided solutions.

The given answer is $462 - 336 + 15 = 141.$

I'll try and see where the terms of the equality above come from.

$[6] = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}.$

The number of all multisets of size six sourced out of $[6]$ is $\binom{6 + 6 -1}{6} = \binom{11}{6} = 462,$ so that's where the first term of $462 - 336 + 15$ come from.

All the multisets of size six where each one contains a digit that occurs at least three times can be rewritten in their type form like so: $$(3, 3), (3, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1, 1), (4, 2), (4, 1, 1),  (5, 1), (6)$$

Then,

$|(3, 3)| + |(3, 2, 1)| + |(3, 1, 1, 1)| + |(4, 2)| + |(4, 1, 1)| + |(5, 1)| + |(6)| \\ = (6 \cdot 5) + (6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4) + (6 \cdot \binom 53) + (6 \cdot 5) + (6 \cdot \binom 52) + (6 \cdot 5) + 6 \\ = 30 + 120 + 60 + 30 + 60 + 30 + 6 \\ = 336.$

So that's where the second term of  $462 - 336 + 15$ must come from.

I am not clear on where $15$ in $462 - 336 + 15$ come from.  So, that's what I'd like to know. Thanks.

Comment: Pick which two numbers both occurred more than twice each.  There are $\binom{6}{2}=\frac{6\cdot 5}{2}=15$ such choices.  For each such choice, the only arrangement possible is to have three of each of the selected numbers.

Comment: @JMoravitz, awesome. I finally understand the logic of this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your count of $336$ is written incorrectly, and the error is directly related to the missing term $15$. You wrote $6\cdot5$ for $|(3,3)|$, but there are in fact only $15$ multisets of type $(3,3)$, not $30$. (Such a multiset is fully determined by one of the $\binom62=15$ choices of two of the six elements.)

The reason that nevertheless $30$ and not $15$ is included in the sum that yields $336$ is that this sum doesn't actually add up the number of multisets in which a digit occurs more than twice (that would already be the solution of the problem); rather, for each condition that a certain number not be included more than twice it counts the number of ways of violating that condition. Since the $15$ sets of type $(3,3)$ violate two of these conditions, they are subtracted twice, and thus we need to add them back in at the next level of inclusion–exclusion by counting the number of multisets that violate at least two of the conditions – namely the $15$ multisets of type $(3,3)$.