# Find the number of six-digit combinations from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$,in which no digit occurs more than twice by way of PIE

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There's this link below, but I have no idea what's going on there (something about types and their cardinalities), so I tried my own way.

[Use PIE to count the number of $6$-multisets of $[6]$ in which no digit occurs more than twice.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317765/use-pie-to-count-the-number-of-6-multisets-of-6-in-which-no-digit-occurs-m)

---

The answer should be $462 - 336 + 15 = 141$.

My attempts:

For example, to show how they got the second term in the given answer I did the following,

- Fix six sets where each number occurs twice like so: $\{1, 1, \_, \_, \_, \_\}, \{2, 2, \_, \_, \_, \_\}, \ldots, \{6, 6, \_, \_, \_, \_\}$ and for each of those choose four numbers out of six with repetitions which gives $6\binom 64 _R = 6\binom94 = 126 \ne 336.$
- Consider the following sets $\{x, x, x, \_, \_, \_\}, \{x, x, x, x, \_, \_\}, \{x, x, x, x, x, \_\}, \{x, x, x, x, x, x\}$. In each of these sets fill in the blanks with integers that are other than $x$ without repetitions. The first one can be done in $\binom 53$ ways. Since there are six integers, there are $6\binom53$ possibilities. Calculting all four disjoint cases and taking their sum gives us $6\binom53 + 6\binom 52 + 6*5 + 6 = 156 \ne 336$.

What I am doing wrong? How can this problem be modeled for the correct solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be the set of 6-multisets that $i$ appears more than twice, for $i \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Elements of $A_i$ have a form like $\{i,i,i,\_, \_, \_\}$. There are at least $3$ $i$'s, not just at least $2$.

Then fill the blanks by e.g. star and bars,
$$|A_i| = \binom{3+6-1}{3} = \binom{8}{3} = 56\\
\sum_{i=1}^{6}|A_i| = 6\cdot\binom83 = 336$$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.